# Replace preg_replace() to preg_replace_callback()

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

```
$source = preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me', "utf8_encode(chr(\\1))", $source);
```

The above code gives deprecated warning.

```
Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in
```

How can I replace preg_replace() to preg_replace_callback() ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the documentation here, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Here is an example of preg_replace_callback

```
$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d+);/m', function($matches){
   return utf8_encode(chr($matches[1]));
}, $source);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$source = preg_replace_callback
(
    '/\&\#(\d+)\;/m',
    function($match){
        return utf8_encode(chr($match[1]));
    },
    $source
);
```