# Problem: mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in

Tags: php

I'm not expert in PHP, my host claims a CPU usage problem on my web site.

I see on error_log a lot of these errors:

> 2023-03-02 11:16:46    Warning 114.119.159.129     mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /data/vhosts/e-compa.com/httpdocs/smforum/Sources/Load.php(225) : runtime-created function on line 3             Errore di Apach

5.6.40  PHP

Do you know how to solve it?

I'm not expert in PHP

Comment: Well you will have to change some code! But we cannot see the code, so its difficult to assist

Comment: Looks like a warning, not an error. It tells you exactly what to do: "The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead"

Comment: Is the line 3 to check?

Comment: search on you code the `preg_replace` function, and post the code, to answer.

Comment: Here a part of code:    global $func;
   return preg_replace(\'~^([ \t\n\r\x0B\x00' . $space_chars . ']|&nbsp;)+|([ \t\n\r\x0B\x00' . $space_chars . ']|&nbsp;)+$~' . ($utf8 ? 'u' : '') . '\', \'\', ' . implode('$string', $ent_check) . ');'),
  'truncate' => create_function('$string, $length', (empty($modSettings['disableEntityCheck']) ? '
   global $func;
   $string = ' . implode('$string', $ent_check) . ';' : '') . '
   preg_match(\'~^(' . $ent_list . '|.){\' . $func[\'strlen\'](substr($string, 0, $length)) . \'}~'.  ($utf8 ? 'u' : '') . '\', $string, $matches);

Comment: Have I to replace some part of code? In which way? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Problem description on the php [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> When using the deprecated e modifier, this function escapes some characters (namely ', ", \ and NULL) in the strings that replace the backreferences. This is done to ensure that no syntax errors arise from backreference usage with either single or double quotes (e.g. 'strlen('$1')+strlen("$2")'). Make sure you are aware of PHP's string syntax to know exactly how the interpreted string will look.

Replace the deprecated funtion `preg_replace()` (on that php version) by the `preg_replace_callback()`, with proper code changes.

Many [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498399/replace-preg-replace-to-preg-replace-callback) to help you like from SO.

Comment: Many duplicates means we don't answer the question, but vote to close it

Comment: @YourCommonSense if the guy posted his code, maybe I could help with the function